# What is exactly MQ-2 sensor?

Tags: sensors

What does the [MQ-2](http://linksprite.com/wiki/index.php5?title=MQ2_Smoke_Detector_Shield_for_Arduino) sensor detect?

I know it detects concentrations of flammable gas. But does it detect smoke from fires too?
What about smoke from cigarettes, and other things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer is no.

There are about 10 similar sensors, each detect specific kind of chemicals